# How to use covariant return types with lists in interface methods?

Tags: java, oop, interface, covariance, software-design

In Object Oriented Programming, "programming to an interface" is often considered a best practice. Since an interface can have many implementations, the idea is that we should be able to swap out one implementation for another with ease. **However, I struggle to understand how to do this when the return type for the interface method is a List.**

As an example, say I need to get data about NBA (basketball) players. Two providers of this data could be ESPN and Yahoo. Both ESPN and Yahoo will provide certain fields of a player, like their `name`. However, ESPN has information about the player's `college` that Yahoo does not. Yahoo might have information about the player's `age`, which ESPN does not.

```
public abstract class Player {
  private String name;
}
```

```
public class EspnPlayer extends Player {
  private String college;
}
```

```
public class YahooPlayer extends Player {
  private int age;
}
```

I want to be able to swap between the ESPN and Yahoo providers, so I write an interface with implementations.
Client Code:

```
public class PlayerController {
  
  public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    NbaService nbaService = new EspnServiceImpl(); // or YahooServiceImpl
    return nbaService.getPlayers();
  }
}
```

Interface and implementations:

```
public interface NbaService {
  List<Player> getPlayers();
}
```

```
public class EspnServiceImpl implements NbaService {

  @Override
  public List<EspnPlayer> getPlayers() {
    List<EspnPlayer> espnPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
    // call ESPN API and get ESPN players
    return espnPlayers;
  }
}
```

This does not compile. I thought that this would work because of covariant return types. Now if I change the interface method to `List<? extends Player> getPlayers();`, everything compiles. However, I'm not sure if this is a good practice. Can someone help me understand what concepts I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that `List<? extends Player> getPlayers();` would not be a good practice?

Comment: @jaco0646 Sonar flagged it with rule "Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types". https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452. So I was wondering if my use case is a bad practice.

Comment: For one of the potential difficulties, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Comment: @Raedwald Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Guess I just wasn't able to Google all the right keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This does not compile.

You have two options:

- Try `List<? extends Player> getPlayers()` in your interface, and now you can write `List<EspnPlayer> getPlayers()` which is a valid implementation if this. Note that it is **not** possible to call `.add()` on this list, for proper reasons (after all, adding a non-EspnPlayer to this list would break the list!)
- If that add thing is required, then there's no way out except to have:

```
interface NbaService<T extends Player> {
    public List<T> getPlayers();
}
```

---

> In Object Oriented Programming, "programming to an interface" is often considered a best practice.

Nice use of the passive voice there, but, as wikipedia editors would say, [citation needed].

There is a grain of truth to this, but as with all programming style suggestions, it's oversimplified. Which isn't a problem, but that's why the following maxim is pretty much always true: If you don't understand the reasons behind a style recommendation, then blindly following it is stupid and will result in worse code. There is no easy out: You must first grok the considerations underlying the recommendation, and until then you just cannot use the recommendation.

Comment: Thank you. I chose to use the "programming to an interface" style recommendation so that I could have the flexibility to swap between implementations. I thought my use case was perfect for it.

Comment: @WarrenCrasta Yeah I think it makes sense here. The use of the passive voice like that just caused my eyebrows to raise.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar to this:

```
List<ESPNPlayers> p = getPlayers();

  @Override
  public <T extends Players> List<T> getPlayers() {
    List<T> players = new ArrayList<>();
    // call ESPN API and get ESPN players
    return players;
  }
}
```

You can also  use generic type parameters in your class declarations to help simplify them.

But unless you specify which type of player you are getting, you will be limited to those fields common to the Player class.

Also, since you subclasses provide new private fields, you will need to provide getters for them.

Finally, programming to an interface like `List` does not mean you can just change the contents of the list.  It means you can change the implementation of the list itself.  And as always, if you need specific features (e.g methods) that only the implementation provides, you must return the implementation type and not the interface type.

Comment: If I have "List<ESPNPlayers> p = getPlayers();", doesn't that tie my client to the ESPN implementation? The objective for me is to "only be limited to those fields common to the Player class." as you mentioned. Therefore, I think it makes more sense to have List<Player> p = getPlayers(); in my client.

Comment: If that is your objective then you are correct.  But then you don't need the other classes that extend Player (at least for this example).  I was just trying to show the method could be used for anything that extends Player.